# Discover Google calendar created with service account

Tags: google-api, google-api-dotnet-client, google-calendar-api

I created new Google calendar with API v3 in c# with Service account. I also set ACL rule:

```
    var permission = new AclRule()
    {
        Scope = new AclRule.ScopeData() { Type = "domain", Value = "mydomain.com" },
        Role = "reader",
    };
```

Problem is how can users of domain "nicely" add this calendar to "Other calendars" in calendar.google.com site?

They can add it if they enter calendar id, which is not user friendly, since id is some random string:

> 4b123456789glvpvasaaaaaaaar4@group.calendar.google.com

. I though I could search by [calendar summary](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/insert). But this is not the case. Only entering complete calendarId adds it to calendar list.

Comment: What exactly is your question? It seams like everything is working for you as it should.  Users must add a calendar using its calendar id which is generated by Google.

Comment: Id is really ugly. My question was can I search by summary on calendar.google.com when adding calendar.